# Access Database creation

Tags: database, entity-relationship, normalization, ms-access-2013, composite-primary-key

I am trying to create a database for hotel reservation system.

In that the Date, Reserved Time (breakfast, lunch or dinner) and Table Number all 3 candidate keys become a composite primary key. In access it's possible to make all these 3 as primary key but when I'm trying to make relationship (Ex:with customer detail table) it's impossible due to there is no unique primary key in this table.

Is there any solution for this?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5_8M-VhW5zoZ3ExRUlvakU4bzQ/view?usp=sharing

Sorry that i don't have privileges to directly add image.
Please be kind enough to refer this link.

Comment: I would gladly help if I would just undestand what you are asking

Comment: Thanks. Isn't my question clear enough for u to understand?

Comment: Amila, can you post a picture of all your tables?  That will help us understand better.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5_8M-VhW5zocWNocHZjdEhJQ1E/view?usp=sharing

thank u for the resonance.
In here i want to do is book a table in the hotel at a specified time of a date with out having duplication booking.
At the same time the invoice is generated only if the booking is done.customer details & cancellation of booking also available  when the booking is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use an AutoNumber field for the primary key instead of having a composite key.  Then you don't have to deal with issues like the Date field being changed in an existing record breaking relationships to other tables.

Comment: but when i use like that it's possible have duplicate reservation for the same table(in the hotel).
ex:there should not be reservation of same table at the same time with in the same date.

Comment: You can prevent that by adding a unique index over those 3 fields.  To do that in the Indexes dialog, add a row for each field and fill in the Index name for just the first one.  Then select the Unique option for that index.

Comment: Thanks.
but when i do like that access only identify only the first field as unique.It doesn't allow me to add same data to that field only. not the combination of all three fields.
please explain me how to solve that.
Thank u.

Comment: This website does a good job of showing how to setup such an index.  Make sure you're following these directions:
http://www.geeksengine.com/article/composite-unique-index-access.html